# Probability of Quadratic form

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

Let, **w , x, y** and **z** be the independent exponential random variables with unit mean. Is there any way to find out the following probability

### $ P(Awx+Bx^2 < Cyz+Dz^2 ) $

where **A, B, C and D** are non-zero positive integers.

Comment: Did you mean to write $ P(Awx+Bx^2< Cyz+Dz^2 )$?

Comment: Oh yes, I will edit it now

Comment: Hint: Use a Laplace Transform to expresses the constraint $A\ldots < \ldots z^{2}$. Even so, I don't know it'll arrive to some 'nice form'.